# Powershell Select -String compare always returning false

Tags: powershell

I've ventured into the realm of Powershell and find myself stuck on what should be a simple task.  I'm looking to compare two strings which contain version numbers from two different files.  For some reason, my compare always returns false:

```
$DLFilePath = "$PSScriptRoot\Download\Update.ini"
$SRCFilePath = "$PSScriptRoot\Original\Update.ini"

#Get File Versions
$DLVersion = Select-String $DLFilePath -pattern "\bVersion" |select line
$SRCVersion = Select-String $SRCFilePath -pattern "\bVersion" |select line

Write-Output "DL Version: " $DLVersion
Write-Output "SRC Version: " $SRCVersion     


if($DLVersion -eq $SRCVersion){
    Write-Output "Files match"

}else {
   Write-Output "Files don't match."
}


--------------Output---------------
    DL Version: 

    Line                                                                                              
    ----                                                                                              
    Version=4.5.2.1233                                                                                
    SRC Version: 
    Version=4.5.2.1233                                                                                
    Files don't match
```

Any idea why the compare is failing?  I originally thought it was because of that "\n Line \n ----"? for the first variable, but I can't figure out where that is coming from.  It only appears the first time I print either one of the variables (If I print the same variable twice in a row, it won't show up a second time), so I assume it has something to do with the output function and not the variable itself?  Also, if I step through the debug and manually print out both variables, it appears on both of them:

```
[DBG]: PS C:\Users\usr\Desktop>> $DLVersion

Line                                                                                              
----                                                                                              
Version=4.5.2.1233                                                                                



[DBG]: PS C:\Users\usr\Desktop>> $SRCVersion

Line                                                                                              
----                                                                                              
Version=4.5.2.1233
```

Comment: `select line` -> `select -exp line`

Comment: Sure enough, that did the trick!  Thanks for the help!

Comment: "*Any idea why the compare is failing?*" - because you're comparing reference equality of objects, not value equality of individual properties of those objects. They're not strings. They're `[Object]`'s with properties called `Line`. And the two objects are not the same thing, even if they happen to have two properties which have the same name and the same value.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I knew Powershell was object based, but I thought the "|select line" was getting me out of the object to just the string. I'll need to go through the documentation more carefully to fully understand what is happening

Comment: Both @PetSerAl and Moose, please help others (the community) by typing the answer below and mark it as a working one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing up @PetSerAl 's comment as an answer.

The problem is that `Select-Object` by default returns one or more PSCustomObject with the same properties only set to be formatted with the property you selected.  Then the comparison ends up being a reference comparison, not a value comparison.

To cause it to return only the value of the property you selected, you need to use `-ExpandProperty`.

Here is the update code:

```
$DLFilePath = "$PSScriptRoot\Download\Update.ini"
$SRCFilePath = "$PSScriptRoot\Original\Update.ini"

#Get File Versions
$DLVersion = Select-String $DLFilePath -pattern "\bVersion" |Select-Object -ExpandProperty line
$SRCVersion = Select-String $SRCFilePath -pattern "\bVersion" |Select-Object -ExpandProperty line

Write-Output "DL Version: " $DLVersion
Write-Output "SRC Version: " $SRCVersion     


if($DLVersion -eq $SRCVersion){
    Write-Output "Files match."

}else {
   Write-Output "Files don't match."
}
```